# How to use "I love you"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

In Italy, you have two options to say "I love you", I'll try to translate them the best I can:

- I love you (*Ti amo.*)
- I want you to be ok (*Ti voglio bene.*)

The fact is that in English, both *ti amo* and *ti voglio bene* are translated as *I love you*. But in Italian, there are lot of differences:

- *I love you* is used to express love for another person which is, or you want her/him to be, your girlfriend/boyfriend.
- *I want you to be ok* is used to express still something love-related but just a little bit less love-related (It's hard to say it). *I want you to be OK* is used by parents to their sons/daughters or vice versa or by a friend to another friend.

I do watch some TV shows in English and I find that sometimes two friends tell each other *I love you* and they just go back to their jobs (= *I want you to be ok*) and sometimes one of them says *I love you* and the other understands that he/she wants her/him to be his/her girlfriend/boyfriend and that it's love-related (= *I love you*).
Why?

Comment: "Ti voglio bene" seems more like "I care about you" or "I care for you" to my ear, since it's literally "I wish you well".

Comment: Yes, but it is used (or at least i do) like a little bit less than "I love you" which implies the presence of the love. "Ti voglio bene" is more for friendship.

Comment: Jon Purdy is correct; the translation for _ti voglio bene_ is _I care of you_. _I want you to be OK_ is quite different.

Comment: People in love can say to each other; *ti amo*, *ti voglio bene*, which can be abbreviated to *TVB*, and *ti voglio tanto bene*. Admittedly a parent might prefer to say to his/her child, *ti voglio bene* rather than ti amo. But otherwise there is no reason why lovers cannot say either.

Comment: Ti voglio bene is more flexible than ti amo, but it does not exclude romantic affection. If you ever visit Italy the walls are sprawled with: [TVTB](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8214/8323896306_6698ff903f_z.jpg) and "(-girlfriend/boyfriend name-)ti voglio bene (-author-)"

Comment: Unfortunately or fortunately I live in Italy so I'm well aware of the use of TVB, TAT, TVTB, TVUKDB and all those acronyms.

Comment: @Jeffrey OMG and LOL "ti voglio un "kasino" di bene"! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In English there are two expressions that partly overlap:

> I love you

and

> I'm in love with you

The second one means romantic love, while the first one can be used for any kind of affection, including romantic.

The first is usually used for both, the second is mostly used when you want to clarify what kind of love you are talking about. Often that is not necessary as it's evident from the situation.

So, it's correct that *I love you* can be used for both Italian expressions. The expression *I'm in love with you* translates into *Ti amo*.

Comment: -1 I'm in love with you in Italian is:**sono innamorato di te**. http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=611847

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Read the question to understand the answer.

Comment: I down-voted your translation. It is inaccurate to say: Ti amo is the English "I'm in love with you". I speak Italian and I was married to an Italian man; I know the difference between the two expressions: *ti amo* and *sono innamorata* ! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I'm sure that you do, but that's not what the question is about. Read the question to unserstand the answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the two expressions you listed are commonly used as terms of affection. Yes, I agree on their difference of usage. Your translation of the latter is, however, inaccurate. In fact, I strongly disagree with the OP's translation of "Ti voglio bene" as: "I want you to be OK". It's not that, it's "voglio che stai bene" which is similar but not identical. I have read the question and obviously I am missing something if you insist on my reading it again. So why not tell me where I am mistaken?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The OP asked about two uses of the same term. In that context *ti amo* corresponds exactly to *I'm in love with you*. A literal translation of the term is irrelevant, as the uses overlap in different ways in the two languages.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I think you are making the translation too much of a big deal. Translation are usually very free. *I'm in love with you* can be translated to "Ti amo" or "Sono innamorata/o di te". The concept is exactly the same as well as the verb "amare" (used in both with different tenses). Also: `I strongly disagree with the OP's translation of "Ti voglio bene" as: "I want you to be OK". It's not that, it's "voglio che stai bene".` just to make you notice: "voglio che stai bene" is **not** a translation for "ti voglio bene".

Comment: I phrased that poorly I admit, I'm sorry. I meant that "voglio che stai bene" *can* be translated to: "I want you to be OK".

Answer (score 6):

I think this is related to the context between the two people. If a friend says "I love you" it is understood to mean that they care for you and want the best for you, but not in a romantic way. I don't think people say "I love you" to someone as a way to *start* a romantic relationship. Typically, those words are said much *later* when one is already *in* a relationship. Also, the *way* in which the words are said ("tone") and the speaker's facial expression when speaking will also allow the hearer to determine what it meant. That's not to say that there are never misunderstandings of course. If friends are not comfortable saying "I love you", they may say "All the best", "I'm thinking of you", "Take care" or "Keep well". These phrases may, however, also be used by people who are not necessarily *close* friends.

Comment: it's more usual to suggest spelling or grammar corrections in comments, not answers.